# error while booting off imac

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, mac

I have some problems while trying to boot from my iMac 2007. Specs:

- 20"
- 2GHz Core 2 Duo
- 4gb ram
- 128mib gpu

<del>https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxpSSIf6jydvN2dSQ2NWaGFmMWc/view?usp=sharing</del> <sup>link dead</sup>

Comment: Note: I'm closing the question because the Google Drive link it contained is no longer working and the remaining information in the post itself is not enough to know what the problem was any more.

Answer (score 3):

You do not specify the boot method, using a DVD or through USB. In either case:

- the Linux kernel has loaded correctly;
- I *think* it has located and loaded the initrd image;
- it is now looking for the main squashfs compressed filesystem, and cannot locate it.

Basically, it cannot find the CD/DVD unit.

As suggested by @WhiteStone, you may have a corrupt image. To complete his reply, I would suggest getting the very latest version of Ubuntu (now 15.04), or at the very least the latest LTS (Long Term Service, now 14.04). There is no rational reason to run 12.04 on your hardware.

I have had luck with Xubuntu 15.04 on a white Macbook of similar age and specs.